# How to check 8 values in SQL database if existing or not?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

So i want to check values in my database if they are existing or not then change the properties of specific buttons and text boxes. if i have 8 values of a certain documents then a label will be equal to 8 if not it i will be equal to how many documents are in the database.

```
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM TBL_Documents WHERE SrCode='" + txtSr.Text + "' AND  DocsName='" + lblRegFrm.Text + "'  ";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {
        lblreg1.Text = "SETTLED";
        lblreg1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        BtnReg.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        lblreg1.Text = "UNSETTLED";
        lblreg1.ForeColor = Color.White;
        BtnReg.Enabled = true;
    }
    con.Close();
```

this is the screenshot of the form

[image]

i dont know where to continue with my current code. there are 8 documents to check to.

Comment: This is quite an open question, could you refine it some more?

Comment: From what I can decipher... you could do a select for the 8 options and check for if x in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), then read whether the 8 items in the DB return null, count how many nulls. Then return 8 - number of nulls in a result set and read that, you can just read each null column field under each header to determine which specific resource is missing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want to know how many results you have and If is more than 8 you do something. So I think you need to do something like this:

```
Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
if (count >= 8)
{
    //do something if it was bigger than 8
}
else
{
    //do something if it is smaller.
}
```